# Insert separators between rows of angular 6 material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have one table of data. This entries are sorted by an id-letter A-E. During listing all these entries, I want to insert a separator after each change of letter. I don't want to make 5 different tables and draw the separators between these.

Is there any possibility to accomplish this? I personally don't think so, because of the way, a material table is coded, but maybe there is a workaround.

The  is no option neither, because it doesn't work inside of a mat-table.